# Conditions on LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query is attempting to show a total count for applications, applications that were approved and applications that went on the be completed for a particular state and ordered by month. So something like this:

```
State    Applications     Approvals     Completed
TX       200              100           50
TX       150              75            48
```

However my counts are coming out way too low. I initially started with sub-queries which I found were WAY to inefficient, so now I'm trying to do it with LEFT JOINS. I would appreciate any ideas as to why my counts are so low or if my conditions within the JOINs are relevant. Also, conditions on whether an application is approved or completed is based on statuses.

```
SELECT  APPU_CUR_STATE,
        COUNT(DISTINCT APPL_ID),
        COUNT(DISTINCT APPD_ID),
        COUNT(DISTINCT APDD_ID)
FROM APPL_APP 
JOIN APPU_APP_USER ON  APPU_APPL_ID = APPL_ID
JOIN APPS_APP_STATUS ON APPS_ID = APPL_APPS_ID
LEFT JOIN APPD_APP_DECISION ON APPL_ID = APPD_APPL_ID  AND APPD_STATUS = 'LENDER_APPROVED'
LEFT JOIN APDD_APP_DEAL_DATA  ON APDD_APPL_ID = APPL_ID AND APPS_STATUS IN('COMPLETE','NOTIFICATION_OF_FUND')
WHERE APPU_CUR_STATE = 'TX'
AND APPL_CREATE_DT >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MONTH(APPL_CREATE_DT);
```

Comment: On which table are the columns APPU_CUR_STATE and APPL_CREATE_DT? If on APPL_APP, make the first too joins also LEFT JOIN to find potential missing values in the secondary tables.

Comment: A wild idea, look into distinct APPU_CUR_STATE if there are any dirty data other than exactly 'TX'. Also, are there too many records with missing APPL_CREATE_DT?

Comment: APPU_CUR_STATE and APPL_CREATE_DT are on separate tables. (APPU_CUR_STATE belongs to APPU_APP_USER and APPL_CREATE_DT belongs to APPL_APP.

Comment: Also, APPU_CUR_STATE wouldn't contain any dirty data as this is already checked. APPL_CREATE_DT will always have a value as well as it is stamped by an internal system.

Comment: Well then try LEFT JOINing to APPS_APP_STATUS, maybe there are APPS_ID's missing there?